# Can I still do a one-way ANOVA with underdispersed data?

Tags: normal-distribution, anova, normality-assumption, qq-plot

My data passes the Levene test for homogeneity of variance, but fails the Shapiro-wilks test by a lot [p=1.818e-12], I have 549 observations [absorbance values] from 3 different temperatures.

The Q-Q plot has tails that disperse from the line at the end, with a sample size as large as this, which I have read can cause the data to fail the normalcy test, does this mean I cannot use the ANOVA? I have included an image of the Q-Q plot.

[image: q-q plot]

Answer (score 0):

First: This has nothing to do with underdispersion, (so I removed that tag).

Then: The qq-plot show that the extremes of the residual distribution is less extreme than expected under the normal distribution assumption.  Look at the right tail: where the theoretical quantile is 3, the standardized residuals flatten out below 2. That kind of deviation from the normal assumption is generally of little import, so you can probably trust the anova analysis.

But you could still do a bootstrap to see!